# CS0246 Error for gRPC Microservice unable to debug

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'TokenRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am trying to build a User Authentication and Authorization gRPC microservice. My `.csproj` file is configured correctly. I have set the `.proto` file property to 'protobuf compiler'. I still get the error every time I try building the app. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me through this. I would really appreciate it.

This is my tokenProvider.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "auth.Protos";


service tokenProvider {
    rpc GetToken (TokenRequest) returns (TokenResponse);
    rpc RegisterUser (RegisterRequest) returns (RegisterResponse);
    rpc Logout (LogoutRequest) returns (LogoutResponse);
    rpc ResetPassword (ResetPasswordRequest) returns (ResetPasswordResponse);
    rpc DeleteAccount (DeleteAccountRequest) returns (DeleteAccountResponse); 
}

message TokenRequest {
    string UserName = 1;
    string Password = 2;
}

message TokenResponse {
    string token = 1;
}

message RegisterRequest {
    string UserName = 1;
    string Password = 2;
    string FirstName = 3;
    string LastName = 4;
}

message RegisterResponse {
    bool Success = 1;
    string Message = 2;
}

message LogoutRequest {
    string Token = 1;
}

message LogoutResponse {
    bool Success = 1;
    string Message = 2;
}

message ResetPasswordRequest {
    string UsernameOrEmail = 1;
    string NewPassword = 2;
}

message ResetPasswordResponse {
    bool Success = 1;
    string Message = 2;
}

message DeleteAccountRequest {
    string UsernameOrEmail = 1;
}

message DeleteAccountResponse {
    bool Success = 1;
    string Message = 2;
}
```

This is my tokenProvider.cs

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Grpc.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using auth;
using auth.Protos;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace auth.Protos
{

    public class tokenProvider
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public tokenProvider(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        //Login Section 
        public override async Task<TokenResponse> GetToken(TokenRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            var user = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == request.UserName && u.Password == request.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var issuer = "https://localhost:5260/"; // Set your JWT issuer here
                var audience = "https://localhost:5260/"; // Set your JWT audience here
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ertwet3245sgf2342werwergww4352345"); // Set your JWT secret key here

                var tokenDescriptor = new JwtSecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {

                     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, request.UserName),
                    // Add other relevant claims here, such as user roles, permissions, etc.
                }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
                    Issuer = issuer,
                    Audience = audience,
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
                };

                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var jwtToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

                // Update the user's token in the database with the new token
                // user.Token = jwtToken;
                // await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();


                // Execute raw SQL UPDATE statement to update the user's token in the database
                var updateSql = $"UPDATE Users SET Token = '{jwtToken}' WHERE UserName = '{request.UserName}';";
                await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(updateSql);
                return new TokenResponse { Token = jwtToken };
            }
            throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.Unauthenticated, "Invalid credentials"));
        }


        public override async Task<RegisterResponse> RegisterUser(RegisterRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            var existingUser = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == request.UserName);
            if (existingUser != null)
            {
                return new RegisterResponse
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "Username already exists. Please choose a different username."
                };
            }

            // var newUser = new User
            // {
            //     UserName = request.UserName,
            //     Password = request.Password,
            //     FirstName = request.FirstName,
            //     LastName = request.LastName,
            //     Token = jwtToken
            // };

            // _dbContext.Users.Add(newUser);
            // await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            var userId = Guid.NewGuid();

            var sql = $"INSERT INTO Users (UserId ,UserName, Password, FirstName, LastName, Token) " +
              $"VALUES ('{userId}';','{request.UserName}', '{request.Password}', '{request.FirstName}', '{request.LastName}', NULL);";
            await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql);

            return new RegisterResponse
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "User registered successfully."
            };
        }


        public override async Task<LogoutResponse> Logout(LogoutRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            var user = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Token == request.Token);
            if (user != null)
            {
                // user.Token = null; // Invalidate the token by setting it to null
                // await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                var updateSql = $"UPDATE Users SET Token = NULL WHERE Token = '{request.Token}';";
                await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(updateSql);
            }
            return new LogoutResponse
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "Logout successful."
            };
        }

        public override async Task<ResetPasswordResponse> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            // Find the user by username or email
            var user = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u =>
                u.UserName == request.Username);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return new ResetPasswordResponse
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "User not found."
                };
            }

            // Update the user's password in the database
            user.Password = request.NewPassword;
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new ResetPasswordResponse
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "Password reset successful."
            };
        }

        public override async Task<DeleteAccountResponse> DeleteAccount(DeleteAccountRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            // Find the user by username or email
            var user = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u =>
                u.UserName == request.Username);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return new DeleteAccountResponse
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "User not found."
                };
            }

            // Delete the user's account from the database
            _dbContext.Users.Remove(user);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new DeleteAccountResponse
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "Account deleted successfully."
            };
        }



    }

}
```